# Android boots, then goes to black screen. adb shell works

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, flutter

Android emulator boots, but shows black screen thereafter.

adb shell works, connecting to the emulated device and giving root access etc without an issue. I've googled everything I can think of, and tried all sorts of stuff. If you have a suggestion I haven't tried, I'd love to hear it.

Things I've tried:

- Delete and reinstall Android studio (basicly, `find $HOME | grep -i "android" | xargs rm -rf`, though manually so as not to kill my projects)
- X86, X86_64, and "armeabi-v7a" ABI's
- Turn on/off using host GPU support/emulation
- Changing memory amount (1.5, 2, 4GB)
- Different API levels (21, 25, 26)
- Rotate device's virtual screen to force a redraw
- Remove hardware from virtual device (camera)
- Creating fresh, brand-new flutter app to run on it.

  - (app doesn't run.
  - claims device is "offline" when I try to run it, despite having shell  access and connecting with adb just fine)
- Swearing a lot.
- Phoning a friend.

Hardware I'm running on:

```
AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
32GB RAM
NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
Linux herb 4.15.0-42-generic #45~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 19 13:02:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Xfce4 (I hate gnome & kde and it's stupid useless eyecandy & bloat)
ZFS file system (2TB capacity 653GB w/ 256G Flash drive configured as cache/zlog)
```

Emulator DOES show the boot screen, either B&W "Android" or fancier google logo depending on the API level. After a few minutes, it goes to a black screen, and refuses to show anything else unless I cold boot it again.

HAXM is not installed. It's not only intel-only, but also windows/mac only, and I'm running linux on an AMD processor.

Comment: What is the output of `flutter run -v`?

Comment: have you HAXM installed?

Comment: Edited post. HAXM *not* installed. AFAICT it's intel only, and I've got an AMD.

Comment: Ouput from flutter run -v is 1K+ lines. here's the pastbin: https://pastebin.com/LtZGBt6Y If it's useful, please copy and paste the relevant bits in your comment, as that link may expire.

Comment: If the emulator doesn't boot this is not related to Flutter. In this case please remove the `flutter` tag from your question.